# Infinite Scroll + .on() function trouble

Tags: javascript, dynamic-data, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to have dynamically loaded content (via the Infinite Scroll script: http://www.infinite-scroll.com/ ) be styled when triggered by an "inview" custom event ( https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview ).

My code looks like this:

```
$(document).on("inview", ".attachment-portfoliosmall", function(e) {
    if( $.data( this, "styleappended" ) ) {
    return true;
    }
    $.data( this, "styleappended", true ); 
    $(".attachment-portfoliosmall").css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn('slow');
    $(".attachment-portfoliosmall").parent(".portfoliopreload").css("background", "none");
});
```

As you can clearly see, the $.data routine is used in order to ensure that the .on() event handler isn't executed more than once for each element in the selection filter.

This code works great in theory, EXCEPT that once the dynamically loaded content on the next page is appended to the document, the .on() routine is being run on every single element a second time, rather than just the newly added elements.

On my website, if you scroll to the next page, you will see all the elements fade out and back in again, which is caused by the `.on()` event handler.

How can I prevent it from being executed on the previously handled elements on the previous page(s)?

Comment: Have you considered adding 'loaded' to your elements class, and filtering on it?

Comment: could you exemplify that in code please? :) i'm very new to javascript and even something that simple seems daunting.

Answer (score 0):

here's what I mean in my comment.

```
$(document).on("inview", ".attachment-portfoliosmall", function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.hasClass('loaded')) {
        $this.addClass('loaded'); 
        $this.css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn('slow');
        $this.parent(".portfoliopreload").css("background", "none");
    }
});
```

Something like that might work for you.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked! Even better, its now only loading the elements when they come into view like I wanted, instead of all of the elements on the page being loaded at once. Perfect! Now to ensure that this is cross-browser compatible *sigh*